# How do I use an array in a switch-case function?

Tags: c

I ask the user to give me 10 integer values for an array A1 and then I print those values onto the console screen. I did/do the same for another array B1. I then print a list of options, for instance option 1: "Sort A1 values in ascending order". Since this is a school assignment I have to use a switch-case statement but I am having trouble accessing the arrays with the same values again and the program is not giving me the option to even press 1, for option one.

I've tried to understand some codes online but with no success, this is what i got so far.

```
  int option;

        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
            case '1':

                for( int i= 0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    for(int x = i +1; x<10; x++)
                    {
                        if (a[x]<a[i])
                        {
                            int temp = a[i];
                            a[i]= a[x];
                            a[x] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                {
                    printf("\n\n Ascending Order For A1: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        printf(" %d ", a[i]);

                    }
```

> > THIS IS HOW FAR I AM WITH THE OUTPUT <<

Please Enter 10 Values For A1: 2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6 4 8

10 Values Chosen For A1: 
2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6 4 8

Please Enter 10 Values For B2: 4 3 7 2 6 8 9 5 8 12

10 Values Chosen For B2: 
4 3 7 2 6 8 9 5 8 12

---

- Please choose one of the following options:                          *
- 1: Sort  A1 values in Ascending Order                           *
- 2: Sort B1 values into Descending Order                         *
- 3: Compute the Sum of the Elements of A1 and B1                 *
- 4: Subtract the Elements of B1 from the Elements of A1          *
- 5: Terminate the program (Exit)                                 *

---

1 <<<<<<<<<<< THIS IS SUPPOSED TO EXECUTE OPTION 1, AND OUTPUT VALUES OF A1 IN ASCENDING ORDER.

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: The best practice would be make a function that's sorts the elements and can it in the case .

Answer (score 0):

you are storing the input in an `int` value, but in your case you are using a `char`, so `1(int)` is not equal to `1(char)` that is the reason the `case '1':` is not executing.
Try

`case 1:`

On the reason why it is not asking for the input to enter the `1` to sort, it might have something in the buffer from previous input, without the rest of the code it is difficult to help you with that part.